# Omitting middle of a list with reprlib

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to format an error message with a list, and would like to include both the start and the end of the list for more useful error messages. For long lists I would like to omit the middle to avoid clutter. `reprlib` seems like the ideal choice for this but I do not see a way to specify which part of a list to omit with `...`. For example I would like to display `mylist` shown below

```
mylist = ["start", "blah", "blah", "blah", "end"]
```

as

```
['start', ..., 'end]
```

however with repr I do not see a way to achieve this. I have tried something like

```
import reprlib
r = reprlib.Repr()
r.maxlist = 2
print(r.repr(mylist))

['start', 'blah', ...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you *know* it's a list (and not some other thing), don't bother with reprlib.  Just build the string yourself:

```
def stringify_list(xs):
    if len(xs) < 3:
        return repr(xs)
    return '[{!r}, ..., {!r}]'.format(xs[0], xs[-1])
```

If you are uncertain of the type, you could do something like this:

```
import functools

stringify = functools.singledispatch(repr)

@stringify.register
def _(xs: list):
    # See previous function body
```

Comment: Yes good call, I guess `reprlib` might be overkill given I know it's a list. One thing I think it should be `<= 2` to avoid `stringify_list(["A", "B"])` returning `"['A', ..., 'B']"`